# Base64 image content security policy error

Tags: http-headers, content-security-policy

I am trying to load a base64 string into an img src, on my local environment this is working but on the live environment I get this error: [click for error:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1JAT8.png)

I also tried putting this in my html header:

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src *; img-src * 'self' data: https:; script-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval' *; style-src  'self' 'unsafe-inline' *">
```

I am really stuck on this issue because I cannot deploy to the live environment because of this.. help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

According to the error message you are missing "data:" for default-src in your initial CSP (remove the quotes). If you define img-src then "data:" should be added to it.

If you don't remove the header when adding the meta tag your all your content must pass both CSPs.

Comment: But I am using an * for default-src so shouldnt it accept everything then?

Comment: Due to the same origin policy "data:" is a different scheme and hence a different origin to http(s) which is the origin of your page. "*" will accept anything on the scheme used to load your page.